# Como consumir de diferentes maneiras arquivos JSON no PHP?

Tags: php, json, array

> Esse tópico difere de assuntos como: ***"Como consumir JSON em
>   PHP"***; ***"Extrair valor json no php";*** ***"Ler string json em
>   php" ou então "Recuperar JSON no PHP"***
>   Embora exista co-relação em vários assuntos da linguagem PHP, e o formato JSON, ele trata de um problema específico, detalhadamente retratado e resumido.

Em todos os materiais que tratam do assunto de JSON em PHP, não encontro nenhum que cite as diferentes formas de tratar o JSON. Tratam o json como se ele fosse expresso sempre da mesma maneira, o que não é verdade na prática. Então, sempre temos um algoritmo para cada maneira que ele é expresso. Existe uma maneira universal de capturar os dados do json, ou existe uma maneira específica para o segundo caso citado abaixo?

Um exemplo prático seria que isso:

```
{  
   "friendslist":{  
      "friends":[  
         {  
            "steamid":"76561197960265731",
            "relationship":"friend",
            "friend_since":0
         },
         {  
            "steamid":"76561197960265738",
            "relationship":"friend",
            "friend_since":0
         },
         {  
            "steamid":"76561197960265740",
            "relationship":"friend",
            "friend_since":0
         },
         {  
            "steamid":"76561197960265747",
            "relationship":"friend",
            "friend_since":0
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**Certamente é diferente disso:**

```
[
   {
      "id":"578",
      "valor":"4.00",
      "CLIENTE":{
         "id":"492",
         "nome":"MARIA",
         "sobrenome":"Machado",
         "endereco":"Avenida das Am\u00e9ricas",
         "latitude":null,
         "longitude":null
      },
      "dataCompra":"DATA_AQUI",
      "PRODUTOS":[
         {
            "id":"14135",
            "codigoDeBarras":"7896015516260",
            "nome":"SONRIDOR",
            "detalhes":"500mg cx 60 comp",
            "categoria":"medicamento",
            "quantidade":"2",
            "precoUnitario":".10"
         }
      ],
      "FRANQUIA":{
         "id":"818",
         "nomeFantasia":null,
         "razaoSocial":null,
         "rede":{
            "id":"32",
            "nome":"Sapataria João"
         },
         "endereco":"Rua Acre",
         "latitude":"-22.899079",
         "longitude":"-43.181612"
      }
   }


]
```

O primeiro caso, até encontro uma forma de leitura

```
$steamid_player = "76561198112612121";
        $apikey = "APIKEY";


       $amg = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=$apikey&steamid=$steamid_player&relationship=friend");
        $decode = json_decode($amg, TRUE);

        foreach ($decode["friendslist"]["friends"][0] as $valor){

            $steamid = $valor["relationship"]->steamid;

            echo $steamid;
        }
```

Mas no segundo caso, não encontrei exemplos práticos. Consigo fazer no máximo um vardump.

Comment: "Tratam o JSON como se ele fosse expresso sempre da mesma maneira". Ele é sempre expresso da mesma maneira. Ele é um padrão para representar dados e se não seguir esse padrão será um JSON inválido. A diferença entre os JSON apresentados são os dados que eles representam. O que você quer dizer com "maneira universal"? (Seu código PHP não funciona)

Comment: É... Não existe "maneiras" de escrever o mesmo formato em outra estrutura de JSON. Talvez seja interessante dar uma olhada sobre a estrutura de objetos em JS para compreende-lo melhor. :)

Comment: [".... A diferença entre os JSON apresentados ..."] Se tem diferenças os JSON apresentados, JSON não é expresso da mesma maneira,  por definição. Da mesma forma que não existe solteiros casados. E sim, existem diferenças da forma que é "expressa" nos dois casos. 
O primeiro caso por exemplo, passa uma coleção de dados expressas e uma sub-coleção em seguida. Ambos arrays, tal que o primeiro array representa uma coleção inteira. No segundo caso, passam 3 arrays interdependentes, sem expressar uma coleção antecedente. O PHP está funcionando normalmente em meu ambiente.

Comment: A quem interessar o problema, o script da resposta não funcionou no PHP5  mas no 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade a forma de leitura é similar ao primeiro exemplo que você citou. Por exemplo, ao usar o json decode eu posso acessar o array clientes, produtos, etc. Veja um exemplo aplicado a sua situação.

```
<?php
//a opção true vai forçar o retorno da função como array associativo.
$conteudo = json_decode(file_get_contents('json.json'), true);

foreach($conteudo as $chave => $elementos){
        $cliente = isset($elementos['CLIENTE']) ? $elementos['CLIENTE'] : [];
        $produtos = isset($elementos['PRODUTOS']) ? $elementos['PRODUTOS'] : [];
        $franquia = isset($elementos['FRANQUIA']) ? $elementos['FRANQUIA'] : [];
        $rede = isset($elementos['FRANQUIA']['rede']) ? $elementos['FRANQUIA']['rede'] : [];

        var_dump($cliente);
        var_dump($produtos);
        var_dump($franquia);
        var_dump($rede);

        /**
        As propriedades de $cliente, $produtos, $franquia, etc, podem ser acessadas da seguinte
        maneira:
        $cliente['id'];
        Aqui você pode manipular os dados da forma que desejar (mandar persistir no banco, etc)
        */
        echo $cliente['id'];

        /*******************Exibição generica*******************************/
        exibir('CLIENTE', $cliente);
        exibir('PRODUTOS', $produtos);
        exibir('franquia', $franquia);
        exibir('rede', $rede);
}

function exibir($titulo, $elementos){
    echo '<br><br>' . $titulo;
    foreach($elementos as $chave => $elemento){
        if(is_array($elemento)){
            foreach($elemento as $chave => $valor){
                echo '<br>' . $chave . ' : ' . $valor;
            }
        }else{
            echo '<br>' . $chave . ' : ' . $elemento;
        }
    }
}
```

As propriedades id, valor, datacompra podem ser acessadas com instruções equivalentes a `echo $elementos['id'];`

Answer (score 3):

JSON é uma forma de serialização de objetos baseada na notação usada para descrever literais de objetos no *javascript*. Sendo assim, a notação deve ser flexível o suficiente para reproduzir qualquer* tipo de objeto que se pode descrever naquela linguagem.

Sendo assim, qualquer mecanismo que analise javascript ou que o emita precisa ser flexível suficiente para emitir qualquer um dos tipos de dados que, compostos, são usados pelo javascript para construir seus objetos.

Os tipos de dado aceitos pelo JSON são seis:

- o objeto nulo `null`;
- os valores *booleanos* `true` e `false`;
- números de ponto flutuante de *pelo menos* 64 bits;
- sequências de caracteres de 8 bits, tipicamente em codificação UTF-8;
- vetores, que são coleções de valores indexados por inteiros contíguos começando por 0; e
- os chamados *objetos* ou *dicionários* ou *hashes*, que são coleções de valores indexados por sequências de caracteres.

Uma biblioteca que analise JSON precisa emitir qualquer um desses seis tipos; por sorte, o PHP tem tipagem dinâmica, então uma única função pode retornar qualquer um dos seis tipos, conforme a necessidade.

Essa função é `json_decode($json, true)`, contanto que o segundo parâmetro seja `true` para que a `json_decode()` retorne um `Array` em vez de um `object`.

Assim, no seu primeiro exemplo, para encontrar o `steamid` do seu terceiro amigo, você diria `$friends = json_decode($exemplo1, true); echo $friends["friendslist"][2]["steamid"];`; para encontrar o sobrenome da cliente no segundo, você diria `$sale = json_decode($exemplo2, true); echo $sale[0]["CLIENTE"]["sobrenome"];`.

*: Na verdade, o JSON é mais restrito que os literais de *javascript* no fato de que não é possível incluir literais de função no JSON, enquanto literais  de *javascript* podem tê-lo.